# check age based on Date of Birth in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to check the Age of a user from the Date Of Birth to make sure Age is between 16 and 80, When the data is inserted into the table

The Date of Birth is a DATE datatype

I have tired looked for multiple solutions and none of them check it when the data is inserted

I have found this help out article to get the current Date with only the Date: [https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-time-in-t-sql/#:~:text=To%20get%20the%20current%20date%20and%20time%20in%20SQL%20Server,20%2010%3A22%3A34%20.](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-time-in-t-sql/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20current%20date%20and%20time%20in%20SQL%20Server,20%2010%3A22%3A34%20.)

But i can't seem to get it to work with the CHECK function when creating the table

Comment: @forpas I was considering dupe-hammering against that post too, but then realized that it only shows how to *calculate* the age, which is not necessary here, all we need is some `WHERE` clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 16 AND 80
```

Not final code, but could be inserted in your scenario hopefully :)

Comment: Thanks, here's my usage of it => DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL CHECK(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 16 AND 80),

Comment: @Moti It's a really bad idea to use `GETDATE()` in a check constraint, and it makes little sense to, as it may work today and fail tomorrow, but the row would have already been inserted.

Answer (score 2):

**The other answer does not correctly deal with partial years.**

For example, given `GETDATE()` as `20220626` and a `DateOfBirth` as `20060627`, a calculation based on `DATEDIFF` will return `TRUE`. This is because `DATEDIFF` just counts the number of date *boundaries* that pass between the two dates.

Another issue is that it cannot use indexes.

A more correct caluclation uses `DATEADD` against the current date:

```sql
WHERE DateOfBirth <= DATEADD(year, -16, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
  AND DateOfBirth >  DATEADD(year, -80, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
```

> You also need `CAST AS date` otherwise you end up with conversion issues

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad7bb4cf6522b52ad963e4af95cdbe6d)